# Mongoose update document with $or condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to search for all activity which has the same `action_object.reply.id` or `action_target.reply.id`. Something like this:

```
Activity
  .find({ $or: [
    { 'action_object.reply.id': replyId }, 
    { 'action_target.reply.id': replyId }
  ]});
```

But i also only want to update the `removed` attribute like this:

```
Activity
  .update({ 'action_object.reply.id': replyId }, {
            'action_object.reply.removed': true }, { multi: true });

Activity
      .update({ 'action_target.reply.id': replyId }, {
                'action_target.reply.removed': true }, { multi: true });
```

Is it possible to somehow combine these two queries? I want to update `action_target.reply.removed` where `action_target.reply.id` or `action_object.reply.removed` where `action_object.reply.id`.

Or i must write two different queries for this like i did above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to the `update` call is the query object, so you can simply use the same $or query. Mongo will update all documents retrieve by the query.

```
Activity
  .update({ $or: [
    { 'action_object.reply.id': replyId }, 
    { 'action_target.reply.id': replyId }
  ]}, {'action_object.reply.removed': true }, { multi: true });
```

Comment: Yes but my problem is, with either document the condition fulfills, it will update `action_object.reply.removed`. I want to update `action_target.reply.removed` in case the second condition applies.

Comment: So you want an $and? So update if only both conditions apply? I'm not sure I get what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i want something like this: Activity.update({condition}, { if (foundDoc === action_object) {'action_object.reply.removed': true} else {'action_target.reply.removed': true}  }, { multi: true });

Comment: Oh I see, I missed the slight variation from `action_target` to `action_object`. In that case, you will have to perform 2 update queries. You can't update a field based on a condition in mongo.

Answer (score 1):

With 4.2, you can use `$cond`

```
// Configuration
[
  {
    "action_object": {
      "reply": {
        "id": "bar",
        "removed": false
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "action_target": {
      "reply": {
        "id": "foo",
        "removed": false
      }
    }
  }
]

// Query
db.collection.update({
  $or: [
    {
      "action_object.reply.id": "foo"
    },
    {
      "action_target.reply.id": "foo"
    }
  ]
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "action_object.reply.removed": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "foo",
              "$action_object.reply.id"
            ]
          },
          true,
          "$$REMOVE"
        ]
      },
      "action_target.reply.removed": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "foo",
              "$action_target.reply.id"
            ]
          },
          true,
          "$$REMOVE"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/tOLh5YKRVX1